# who to fix "Failed to enable crypto" on windows 10

Tags: php, wordpress, smtp

I am seeing following error when trying to send mail by SMTP on wordpress

```
Connection: opening to ssl://smtp.gmail.com:465, timeout=300, options=array (
                                      )
2017-09-06 17:16:09 Connection: Failed to connect to server. Error number 2. "Error notice: stream_socket_client(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
                                      error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed
2017-09-06 17:16:09 Connection: Failed to connect to server. Error number 2. "Error notice: stream_socket_client(): Failed to enable crypto
2017-09-06 17:16:09 Connection: Failed to connect to server. Error number 2. "Error notice: stream_socket_client(): unable to connect to ssl://smtp.gmail.com:465 (Unknown error)
2017-09-06 17:16:09 SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server:  (0)
2017-09-06 17:16:09 SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting
```

I have seen solutions specifying cacert.pem, but doesn't worked for me. I am using windows 10. I tried with WTServer and Wamp.